# c#. How to handle server response while still uploading a large request body?

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

We have a .net core web API for [uploading large files with streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming-1):

```
[HttpPost("file")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile()
{
   // parse multipart request body
   var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
   var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
   while (section != null)
   {
         var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition);
         if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
         {
            // file
            if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
               var fileName = contentDisposition.FileName.Value;
               var contentType = section.ContentType;

               // extension whitelist
               string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Trim('.');
               if (!fileExtensionWhitelist.Select(_ => _.Extension).Any(s => s.Equals(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
               {
                     return BadRequest("Forbidden file extension")
               }

               var fileStream = section.Body;
               // upload file
            }
            // other form data
            else if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
               // other data
            }
         }

         section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
   }

   return Ok(fileId);
}
```

Now I am trying to implement client code for uploading files.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream, 5242880/*5MB*/)
    {
        Headers =
        {
            ContentLength = fileStream.Length,
            ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName)),
        }
    }, "file", fileName);

    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        request.Content = content;
        request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(_url);

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // parse response
    }
}
```

So everything works as expected until I try to upload a file with a forbidden extension: The server detects this extension and returns the BadRequest object. But the client still trying to upload the multipart request (files can be up to 1GB). It leads to this Exception:

> The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

I understand that this is happening because the HttpClient doesn't read the response until it sends the entire request body, but the server has already stopped processing this request. So is there a way to handle this situation?

Comment: Can't you just add a method on the sever to tell the client whether the extension is allowed, which you can call before uploading?

Comment: Have you tried providing the `HttpCompletionOption` parameter to the overload when sending the request? `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption, CancellationToken)`. You can try the value `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. Otherwise, I suggest just wrapping your SendAsync operation in a try-catch block and handling it that way. There isn't much reference material out there discussing async stream uploads with HttpClient.

Comment: @stuartd Sure that is the way to go if there is no other solution to the problem

Comment: @jandrew HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead doesn't help in this situation. Is there a way to read the response in the catch block?

Comment: @pr3sto You can definitely read the exception message from the catch block but it looks like the exception is actually coming from the `StreamContent` object and not a `HttpRequestException`, so I don't know how useful it's going to be. For a bandaid fix, I'd just catch any exceptions and assume it's an unauthorized file type. I think there's a way to properly do this with the HttpClient but the documentation is pretty sparse for anything detailed or outside of basic requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the error to the [SerializeToStreamAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/MultipartContent.cs#L176) method inside `MultipartContent` class:

```cs
protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
{
    // other code
   
    TaskCompletionSource<Object> localTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();
    
    // somewhere here we get the error
    // it results in setting the exception on the task
    localTcs.TrySetException(ex);

    return localTcs.Task;
}
```

This exception tells `HttpClient` that the request failed. So `HttpClient` doesn't even try to read the response.

So I created my own implementation of [MultipartFormDataContent](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/MultipartFormDataContent.cs). It is the same as Microsoft's implementation, but with overridden `SerializeToStreamAsync` method:

```cs
public class CustomMultipartFormDataContent : MultipartContent
{
// implementation from https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/MultipartFormDataContent.cs

protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    Task task = base.SerializeToStreamAsync(stream, context);
    task.ContinueWith(copyTask =>
    {
        if (copyTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            var exception = copyTask.Exception.GetBaseException();
            if (exception.GetType().Equals(typeof(NotSupportedException)))
            {
                // We assume that our multipart request is usually large, as we want to send large files over http.
                // The nature of http communication is: we send the whole request to the server and only then reads the response.
                // But the server can abort the request and send the response, while we are still sending large request.
                // This situatuion leads to concurrent read/write operations on the http stream which leads to NotSupportedException.
                // Here we try to catch this exception, abort sending of the request and start reading the response.
                tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(exception);
            }
        }
        else if (copyTask.IsCanceled)
        {
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }
    },
    CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    
    return tcs.Task;
}

} // CustomMultipartFormDataContent
```

When the code catches `NotSupportedException` it doesn't set the exception on the task. In that case, for the `HttpClient` it looks like the request was sent successfully and it will try to read the response.

And the changes for the client code:

```cs
// var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(); <- old code
var content = new CustomMultipartFormDataContent();
```

Comment: In my case, the REST API was returning a 415 UnsupportedMediaType, but the NotSupportedException masked it until I implemented this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not resolve the problem but it's worth a try. Try wrapping the SendAsync method in a using block and then parse the response from within there. Also, watch how you're parsing the response.

```cs
using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken))
{
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
    // Do whatever with response content ...
}
```

Also, the recommended way to manage  HttpClient instances is through the `IHttpClientFactory`. I won't go into detail on usage but you may consider checking the docs as you can run into problems by simply new'ing up a HttpClient object.

Comment: `_httpClient.SendAsync` throws the exception (The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations), so using block doesn't solve the problem.